# Java Calendar 'getTimeInMillis()' causes all 'isSet' fields to be true

Tags: java, calendar

I am very confused by the following unexpected behavior of Java Calendar

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.clear();
//System.out(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.setLenient(false);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

If I call getTimeInMillis() after the 'clear()', all the isSet() fields which were false after the clear() become true. What am I doing wrong? If this is the correct behavior (which seems very odd) is there a way to stop it?

Comment: You should really avoid using the legacy `java.util.Calendar` class if you can possibly avoid it.  You should instead use the appropriate class in the `java.time` package.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: `getTimeInMillis()` is a getter with the side-effect to set fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

**Never use awful `Calendar`** class.

Use modern *java.time* classes. These [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) avoid entirely the problems you found.

```
ZonedDateTime                   // Represent a moment using the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
.now(                           // Capture the current moment.
    ZoneId.systemDefault()      // Get the JVM’s current default time zone. Beware: This can change at any moment during runtime. If crucial, confirm with user.
)                               // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.withYear(                      // Per the immutable objects pattern, produce another object based on the original’s values but with a change.
    2001                        // Change the year, but copy the month, day-of-month, hour, minute, second, fractional second, and time zone all the same. If the time-of-day is not valid on that date in the other year, auto-adjust per algorithm documented in the JavaDoc.
)                               // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## java.time

The terrible `Calendar` class is obsolete, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

To capture the current moment in UTC, use `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

From that `Instant` you can get a count of milliseconds since the same epoch reference as `Calendar`: the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Beware of data loss, as the resolution of `Instant` is nanoseconds, much finer than milliseconds used in the legacy date-time classes such as `Calendar`.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = instant.toEpochMilli() ;
```

You can create an `Instant` from that number.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisecondsSinceEpoch) ;
```

To see that moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) // Or your JVM’s current default, ZoneId.systemDefault().
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To change the year as you did in the Question, call [`withYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withYear(int)).

```
ZonedDateTime zdtOtherYear = zdt.withYear( 2001 ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: The project I am working on IS for Android versions 4.3+. I do need a lot of complex time operations manipulating time data (which may be stored and thus old) from remote (located anywhere in the world) medical equipment. Hopefully the time class supports a generic GMT+/-xxxx. Medical times also need to support -0000 time zone which means time follows UTC but location is unknown. I had to do some extra sweat to support that using Calendar.

Comment: For an offset-from-UTC, use the `ZoneOffset` and `OffsetDateTime` classes.  Your spécial meaning of negative zero offset does not mean *location* unknown, as location is irrelevant to date-time handling, it means offset-from-UTC is unknown. This special meaning is explicitly forbidden in ISO 8601. In other words a zero offset can only be positive `+00:00`, never negative `-00:00`. Unfortunately, the renegade [RFC 3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339) claims to be a “profile” of ISO 8601 while violating this explicit rule. For unknown, instead use *no* offset and the `LocalDateTime` class.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It may be forbidden in ISO 8601 but it has been adopted by HL7 FHIR and other standards as a means to distinguish between UTC-offset unknown and UTC actually in a UTC zone like England. Your comments are very helpful

Comment: After playing with Java.time for just a few minutes I see it would greatly simplify my life. Unfortunately support for Android >= 15 is needed and ThreeTen-Extra is a third party library which excludes me from using it. I will have to wait until Android adds support for it in one of its support libraries. But given the formats of the time strings in the standards I need to support java.time would be great! I can handle the -00:00 quite easily in my FHIR DateTime class during serialization.

Comment: I have seen your other answers with regard to the Java.time classes. You are clearly a residing expert in this domain!

Answer (score 2):

In refer to [Calendar javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> Getting and Setting Calendar Field Values
>
> The calendar field values can be set by calling the set methods. Any field values set in a Calendar will not be interpreted until it needs to calculate its time value (milliseconds from the Epoch) or values of the calendar fields. Calling the get, getTimeInMillis, getTime, add and roll involves such calculation.

By calling `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` values are set. This is the correct behavior and you cannot stop it. As Joe mentioned, you should switch to `java.time` package, if possible.

Comment: I read the doc and it's not how I interpreted it. Since the only thing I had actually set was nothing, I expected to get 0 (the epoch start time). I set individual fields based upon what the input strings are. It may be just the year, year+month, etc all the way down to milliseconds.  It sounds like what you are saying is that I need to keep track of what I set, call the getTimeInMillis() and then re-clear all those fields I never set. BLAH!!!

Comment: I tried the above just for the fun of it and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

That's generally one should not use `Calendar` or `Date` as they are mutable and some of the API methods are unpredictable (e.g. lenient by default). `java.time` is a better choice in modern codebase.

As per `Calendar.isSet()` javadoc

> Determines if the given calendar field has a value set,
>   including cases that the value has been set by internal fields
>   calculations triggered by a `get` method call.

`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` may set the calendar position to current time however this can depend on the Java version. With OpenJDK 11.0.1 below code prints only `false` so no fields are being set by `getTmeInMillis()`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
IntStream.range(0, 17).mapToObj(cal::isSet).forEach(System.out::println);
cal.getTimeInMillis();
IntStream.range(0, 17).mapToObj(cal::isSet).forEach(System.out::println);
```

However replacing `cal.getTimeInMillis()` with `cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)` will print all `true` in the second `IntStream`.

Comment: I will check java.time. If it is not a third party library and supports time zones that may be a good solution. It will require a great deal of work on my part though....

Comment: `java.time` is there since [Android 8.0 (API Level 26)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary)

Comment: Before Android 26, use the ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects to get most of the *java.time* functionality with nearly identical API.

Answer (score 0):

Since I could not use the java.time package (it is not supported on Android versions I need to support) and third-party packages I had to make my own class based upon the Calendar where I had to independently keep track of what is set and what is not. I needed to preserve this information in order to express time stamps in HL7 FHIR resources with the correct time precision. An annoyance and a pain but it does what I need.